# imtranslate command matlab show me a black image

Tags: image, matlab, coordinates, system

I'm trying to translate an image read through imshow function, but the output is a black image.

Here's the code:

```
fingers=imread('thumb-index.png');

[nrows,ncols] = size(fingers);

RI = imref2d(size(fingers));
h = imshow(fingers,RI);
grid on

x_center=ncols/2;
y_center=nrows/2;

x_orig=ncols-x_center;
y_orig=nrows-y_center;

[fingers_translate,RF]=imtranslate(fingers,RI,[x_orig,y_orig]);
figure

h=imshow(fingers_translate,RI);
grid on
```

My target is translating the origin of coordinate system in the center of the image.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you pushed the image out of frame. To see translation effect try:

```
x_orig=100;
y_orig=100;
```